# Bzr Eclipse Plugin not configurable

Tags: eclipse, bazaar

I'm relatively new to Eclipse. I'm currently running bzr 2.2.1 and Eclipse 3.5.2 (Galileo). Following the directions at:

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrEclipse/Installation

I get to the point where it tells me the plugin has been successfully installed, but when I attempt to configure it at Window --> Preferences --> Team --> Bazaar, there's no "Bazaar" there. Team shows CVS, File Contents, Ignored Resources and Models.  (Nothing useful under CVS.) Nothing in ~/workspace/.metadata/.log about bzr either.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin a few times, to no avail.  Is there a more thorough way to uninstall that plugin without removing everything else that's been installed?

Is there somewhere else I should be looking for the source of trouble? I didn't see anything promising on Launchpad, but may not have looked deep enough.

Comment: does your bazaar install work at all from the cli?  if it isn't functioning the rest of this is a moot point.

Comment: If I understand your question, yes.  I've been using bzr from the command line for several years, albeit, not necessarily taking full advantage of its power.  (I wrote a short tutorial on basic usage a few years ago as well.)  It's still working fine a la CLI.

Comment: yes you understood what i was trying to ask.  I would guess that it has something to do with Java or eclipse environment variables.  I have had weird problems similar to this when I install Java the ubuntu way.  That's why for things like Java and Ruby I just handle the manual install and env variable settings myself and shovel everything to opt.  I probably won't be much help though since my java isn't "out-of-the-box" configured.  If I have time, I'll do a fresh install in a vm and see if I can replicate this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug filed in Launchpad on this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-eclipse/+bug/709210

Currently, I'm trying to install bzr-eclipse in Maverick 64bit running in Virtual Box. Let's what this gives.

Bazaar installation on command line works; verified by branching lp:bzr.